# Roswell - How to start a new project?

Tags: common-lisp, project

Just getting started with Common Lisp, Roswell and SBCL.  I have completed the [Initial Recommended Setup](https://roswell.github.io/Initial-Recommended-Setup.html) and am able to work with [Lem IDE](https://github.com/lem-project/lem/)  repl.  Now I want to get going with a new project, but how to initialize a new project with Roswell?  Basically I expect to find something similar to [cargo new](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/creating-a-new-project.html).

```
$ ros help new
No manual entry for ros-new
```

`ros help` shows possible sub-commands.  The closest seems to be `ros init`, but it simply produces a script wrapper to `exec` the Lisp code from the command line.

```
commands:
   run       Run repl
   install   Install a given implementation or a system for roswell environment
   update    Update installed systems.
   build     Make executable from script.
   use       Change default implementation.
   init      Creates a new ros script, optionally based on a template.
   fmt       Indent lisp source.
   list      List Information
   template  Manage templates
   delete    Delete installed implementations
   config    Get and set options
   version   Show the roswell version information
```

Comment: There is an example here: https://github.com/roswell/roswell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I described a possibility [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-set-up-common-lisp-ide-in-2021-5be70d88975b?sk=b178a230dc2ba72c2a5af7ea86857fc0).
If you install `cl-project` package via Roswell, it installs a script `make-project` which you can call from the command line for starting a new project.

In short:

```
# install cl-project
$ ros install fukamachi/cl-project
# enter Roswell's local-project folder
# where you have to create the project
# so that it can be found by Roswell:
$ cd ~/.roswell/local-projects

# as and example we create a project caled `my-project`:
$ make-project my-project --depends-on alexandria cl-xlsx

# you can see the folder structure:

$ tree my-project
my-project
├── my-project.asd
├── README.markdown
├── README.org
├── src
│   └── main.lisp
└── tests
    └── main.lisp
2 directories, 5 files


# my-project/my-project.asd
# contains:

(defsystem "my-project"
  :version "0.1.0"
  :author ""
  :license ""
  :depends-on ("alexandria"
               "cl-xlsx")
  :components ((:module "src"
                :components
                ((:file "main"))))
  :description ""
  :in-order-to ((test-op (test-op "my-project/tests"))))
(defsystem "my-project/tests"
  :author ""
  :license ""
  :depends-on ("my-project"
               "rove")
  :components ((:module "tests"
                :components
                ((:file "main"))))
  :description "Test system for my-project"
  :perform (test-op (op c) (symbol-call :rove :run c)))

# you can then adjust other data in that file - like fill in description, author name etc.

# some of the infos you can enter already
# while calling the command line command:

$ make-project
Usage:
    make-project /home/user/common-lisp/sample \
--name sample \
--description "sample project." \
--author "Your name" \
--license LLGPL \
--depends-on alexandria split-sequence
```

Comment: Apparently Roswell doesn't include project management, correct?  Okay.  Is `cl-project` more harmonious with Roswell than `quickproject` by Xach or other options?  Thank you very much for these answers.

Comment: @VesnaK. `cl-project` plays better with Roswell and has integrated test setup. But especially, it supports command line commands (thanks to Roswell), while quickproject you can run only from inside lisp.

Comment: Very good.  I'm making some progress.  Thanks again.